# how to edit facebook events using graph api?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing in which i am getting my events and my friends events using facebook graph api, now i need to perform following function.

1. Change event's location name.
2. Change event's location latitude and longitude.
3. Get event's Admin.

I have searched a lot but i couldn't get healthy response and solution, so please any body help me to get rid of this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/
You can change the name of the event location using the 'Location' field. Also the event owner can be retrieved with the 'Owner' field.

To change the long/lat you will need to edit the 'venue' field. Which according to to API docs is an 'object containing one or move of the following fields: street, city, state, zip, country, latitude, and longitude fields'